# Unable to run Java program that imports org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, lucene, mahout

I'm unable to run a java program that imports org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.BayesUtils;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.NaiveBayesModel;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.StandardNaiveBayesClassifier;
import org.apache.mahout.common.Pair;
import org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.sequencefile.SequenceFileIterable;
import org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector.Element;
import org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DefaultAnalyzer;
import org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.TFIDF;

import com.google.common.collect.ConcurrentHashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;


public class Classifier {

 public static Map<String, Integer> readDictionnary(Configuration conf, Path dictionnaryPath) {
  Map<String, Integer> dictionnary = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  for (Pair<Text, IntWritable> pair : new SequenceFileIterable<Text, IntWritable>(dictionnaryPath, true, conf)) {
   dictionnary.put(pair.getFirst().toString(), pair.getSecond().get());
  }
  return dictionnary;
 }

 public static Map<Integer, Long> readDocumentFrequency(Configuration conf, Path documentFrequencyPath) {
  Map<Integer, Long> documentFrequency = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();
  for (Pair<IntWritable, LongWritable> pair : new SequenceFileIterable<IntWritable, LongWritable>(documentFrequencyPath, true, conf)) {
   documentFrequency.put(pair.getFirst().get(), pair.getSecond().get());
  }
  return documentFrequency;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  System.out.println("Start time :" + System.currentTimeMillis());
  if (args.length < 5) {
   System.out.println("Arguments: [model] [label index] [dictionnary] [document frequency] [tweet file]");
   return;
  }
  String modelPath = args[0];
  String labelIndexPath = args[1];
  String dictionaryPath = args[2];
  String documentFrequencyPath = args[3];
  String testFilePath = args[4];

  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

  // model is a matrix (wordId, labelId) => probability score
  NaiveBayesModel model = NaiveBayesModel.materialize(new Path(modelPath), configuration);

  StandardNaiveBayesClassifier classifier = new StandardNaiveBayesClassifier(model);

  // labels is a map label => classId
  Map<Integer, String> labels = BayesUtils.readLabelIndex(configuration, new Path(labelIndexPath));
  Map<String, Integer> dictionary = readDictionnary(configuration, new Path(dictionaryPath));
  Map<Integer, Long> documentFrequency = readDocumentFrequency(configuration, new Path(documentFrequencyPath));


  // analyzer used to extract word from tweet
  Analyzer analyzer = new DefaultAnalyzer();

  int labelCount = labels.size();
  int documentCount = documentFrequency.get(-1).intValue();

  System.out.println("Number of labels: " + labelCount);
  System.out.println("Number of documents in training set: " + documentCount);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFilePath));

  String outputFile = "/home/hduser/result.txt";
  FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter(outputFile,true); 
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(f1);



  int correctCounter=0;
  int totalCounter=0;
  while(true)
  {
   String line = reader.readLine();
   if (line == null) {
    break;
   }

   String[] arr = line.split(" ");
   String catId = arr[0];
   String label = arr[1];

   String msg = line.substring(arr[0].length() + arr[1].length() + 2);


   Multiset<String> words = ConcurrentHashMultiset.create();

   // extract words from Msg
   TokenStream ts = analyzer.reusableTokenStream("text", new StringReader(msg));
   CharTermAttribute termAtt = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
   ts.reset();
   int wordCount = 0;
   while (ts.incrementToken()) {
    if (termAtt.length() > 0) {
     String word = ts.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString();
     Integer wordId = dictionary.get(word);
     // if the word is not in the dictionary, skip it
     if (wordId != null) {
      words.add(word);
      wordCount++;
     }
    }
   }

   // create vector wordId => weight using tfidf
   Vector vector = new RandomAccessSparseVector(10000);
   TFIDF tfidf = new TFIDF();
   for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry:words.entrySet()) {
    String word = entry.getElement();
    int count = entry.getCount();
    Integer wordId = dictionary.get(word);
    Long freq = documentFrequency.get(wordId);
    double tfIdfValue = tfidf.calculate(count, freq.intValue(), wordCount, documentCount);
    vector.setQuick(wordId, tfIdfValue);
   }
   // With the classifier, we get one score for each label 
   // The label with the highest score is the one the tweet is more likely to
   // be associated to
   Vector resultVector = classifier.classifyFull(vector);
   //double bestScore = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
   double bestScore =Double.MAX_VALUE;
   int bestCategoryId = -1;
   String resultStr=catId+" ";
   for(Element element: resultVector) 
   {
    int categoryId = element.index();
    double score = -1 * element.get();
    if (score < bestScore) {
     bestScore = score;
     bestCategoryId = categoryId;
    }
    //System.out.print("  " + labels.get(categoryId) + ": " + score);
    if(resultStr.equalsIgnoreCase(catId + " "))
    {
     resultStr=resultStr + labels.get(categoryId) + " " + score;
    }
    else
    {
     resultStr=resultStr + "   " + labels.get(categoryId) + " " + score;
    }
   }
   try
   {

     out.write(resultStr);
     out.write("\n");

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {

   }

   //System.out.println(label + " => " + labels.get(bestCategoryId));
   out1.write(label + " => " + labels.get(bestCategoryId));
    out1.write("\n");
   totalCounter++;
    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase(labels.get(bestCategoryId)))
    {

     correctCounter++;
     System.out.println("correctCounter : " + correctCounter);
    }
  };
   //Close the output stream
  System.out.println("correctCounter : " + correctCounter + " TotalCounter :" + totalCounter);
  System.out.println("End time :" + System.currentTimeMillis());
  System.out.println("Accuracy : " +  (double)correctCounter/totalCounter);
   out.close();
 }
}
```

Configurations on my ubuntu system: Hadoop 1.2.0, Mahout 0.7, Lucene 1.4.1, Java 1.6

I compiled the java program without any errors and generated a jar file:

```
java c -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/*:/usr/local/mahout/*:/usr/local/lucene/* -d Classifier_Class/ Classifier.java

jar -cvf Classify.jar -C Classifier_CLass/ .
```

When I tried executing this jar using hadoop I'm facing the following error:

```
hadoop jar Classify.jar {input arguments}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Try giving jar file name as well in -classpath option so like /home/root/lib/lucene-api.jar

Comment: I have tried including the classpath in the command hadoop -cp /usr/local/mahout/lib/lucene-core-4.10.1.jar -jar /usr/local/hadoop/Classify.jar, but even now the same issue.

Comment: Hadoop script wont take -cp so better you define a variable called CLASSPATH or HADOOP_CLASSPATH (if you are using HADOOP) and then run your java or hadoop script.

Comment: i'm using Hadoop, could you please let me know on adding HADOOP_CLASSPATH. For your information, i have already defined HADOOP_HOME in my bashrc file

Comment: define HADOOP_CLASSPATH and CLASSPATH in your bashrc. Source it and rerun your hadoop command.

Comment: In my bashrc file i have added export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/mahout/lib and tried to run the below code hadoop jar Classify.jar {input arguments}. Even now its the same error i'm facing.

Comment: I have tried even doing this way java -cp /usr/local/lucene/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.10.1.jar/:/usr/local/lucene/core/lucene-core-4.10.1.jar:/usr/local/lucene/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.1.jar -jar /usr/local/hadoop/Classify.jar {input arguments}, but no use

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you build the jars of your application, the maven dependences of Lucene (.jar files) are not included in your jars, that is, Java cannot find the Lucene's classes that your application use. I had the same issue with the same stack trace.

You should better use Maven to build your project.

What you have to do, is to build your sources with the dependences and then, your compiled application will include the Lucene's jars.

To do this, just add these lines of code in your .pom file of the Maven project

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>    
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                     <id>make-assembly</id>
                     <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>                         
                       <goal>single</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now, run your application: `hadoop jar APP_NAME-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

All the above will resolve your issue.